# Hide html element based on every attribute value jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following ticket table in which I'd like to hide the ticket ID, yellow highlited.

[image]

By inspecting the code, this can be achived as hiding **every** element with **any** value specified by the attribute `data-test-ticket-id` in the `span` class.

```
<td>
    <div>
        <span data-test-ticket-id="2595" class="muted">
        #2595
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

The coded table can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/f6qkgL54/

I tried `td.div.span { display: none !important; }`. I think the best method would be using jquery but I have some difficulties.

**Edit**

I can't use .muted `{ display: none; }` because it is used almost everywhere in the system so it will hide important elements

Comment: just use .mute{display: none }

Comment: Hi, Since you have notified that yiu have other muted element elsewhere in the page - please see my updated answer below which will only hide the `muted` class from the `table` you have. I have added `two demo span's` outside as well to show that they are not being hidden but the `ticket ID;'s` are not showing anymore.

Comment: Hi! I really appreciate your help. Is there a way to generate dynamic css using that function? I.e. inject dyamically {display: none}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use jQuery `$.each` on your `.muted` class and hide all the span using `.hide()` method

**Edit:** See my updated answer below which will only hide the `muted` class from the `table` you have. I have added `two demo span's` outside as well to show that they are not being hidden but the `ticket ID;'s` are not showing anymore.

```
$('table tbody tr td').each(function(){
   $(this).find('span.muted').hide() //hide all spans with ticket id's only from table
})
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('table tbody tr td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('span.muted').hide() //hide all spans with ticket id's only from table
})
```

```css
.muted {
  background: green;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="">
  <tbody class="lt-body">
    <!---->
    <tr data-test-id="ticket-row-2595" data-row-id="ember2353" colspan="1" id="ember2354" class="lt-row is-selectable current__item--active ember-view">
      <td style="width: 50px" id="ember2355" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div id="ember2356" class="ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="table-checkbox" id="ember2357" class="input __ui-form__custom-checkbox custom-checkbox ember-view"><input data-test-checkbox="ticket-checkbox-ember2357" id="checkbox-ember2357" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-checkbox ember-view" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-ember2357">
              <span class="label-field"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 12vw" id="ember2358" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="customer_test_label" id="ember2359" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div class="avatar-info-cell">
            <div class="avatar-image">
              <figure data-test-user-avatar="" id="ember2361" class="profilepic  avatar-icon avatar-icon--small avatar-icon--circle ember-view"> <span data-test-avatar-text="profile_font_text" id="ember2362" class="avatar-block avatar__initial avatar__initial--3 ember-view"><span class="avatar__initial--icon-wrapper">
                    A
                  </span>
                </span>

                <!---->
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div data-test-id="table-view-contact" id="ember2363" class="avatar-text text__content requester-hover ember-view">
              <div id="ember2364" class="ember-view">
                <div data-test-id="user-link" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3925" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3925-trigger" role="button" id="ember3926" class="ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <a href="/a/contacts/77039479587" data-test-id="user-name" class="user">
                    Anyonio M
                  </a>

                </div>
                <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3925" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>



              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 30px" id="ember2366" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-autorefresh ember-view">
        <!---->
      </td>
      <td style="width: 24vw" id="ember2368" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="subject_test_label" id="ember2369" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div id="ember2370" class="pr-12 ticket-listview-hover __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__ticket-subject-popover ember-view">
            <div id="ember2371" class="ember-view">
              <div data-test-id="ticket-subject-hover-2595" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3809" tabindex="-1" data-ebd-id="ember3809-trigger" role="button" id="ember3810" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <a data-test-link="tickets-subject-2595" href="/a/tickets/2595" id="ember3811" class="link-on-hover link-no-underline wordbreak-fix text--extra-bold ember-view">M / Test - Test (MI) #210510
                  <span data-test-ticket-id="2595" class="muted">
                    #2595
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3809" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>



            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 400px" id="ember2373" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="_test_label" id="ember2374" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="assign-to-hover" id="ember2375" class="group-agent ember-view">
            <div data-test-id="group-agent" id="ember3844" class="__module-tickets__assign-to ember-view">
              <div class="group-field  pr-5 mb-0">
                <div data-test-id="group-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Gruppo">

                  <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3846" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3846-trigger" role="button" id="ember3847" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> Product

                    </span>
                    <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3846" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="agent-field border-left--none">
                  <div class="agent-filter pl-0 mt-0">
                    <div data-test-id="agent-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Agente">

                      <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3852" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3852-trigger" role="button" id="ember3853" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> --

                        </span>
                        <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3852" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2377" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="priority_test_label" id="ember2378" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="priority-hover" id="ember2379" class="priority ember-view">
            <div class="list-filter__label">
              <span class="tickets__list--low tickets__list--dropdown"></span> Low
              <!---->
            </div>

            <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon priority-icon"></span>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2381" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="statusTranslatedLabel_test_label" id="ember2382" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="status-hover" id="ember2383" class="status-select ember-view">
            <div class="pull-left list-filter__label" aria-label="Stato">
              Open
              <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2384" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="company.name_test_label" id="ember2385" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 180px" id="ember2386" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="createdAt_test_label" id="ember2387" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> 23º set 2020, 06:21 PM
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2388" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2389" class="hcell-template ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 200px" id="ember2390" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="stats.requesterRespondedAt_test_label" id="ember2391" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2392" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2393" class="hcell-template ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2394" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_checkbox_test_label" id="ember2395" class="hcell-template ember-view"> No
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-test-id="ticket-row-2454" data-row-id="ember2396" colspan="1" id="ember2397" class="lt-row is-selectable ember-view">
      <td style="width: 50px" id="ember2398" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div id="ember2399" class="ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="table-checkbox" id="ember2400" class="input __ui-form__custom-checkbox custom-checkbox ember-view"><input data-test-checkbox="ticket-checkbox-ember2400" id="checkbox-ember2400" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-checkbox ember-view" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-ember2400">
              <span class="label-field"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 12vw" id="ember2401" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="customer_test_label" id="ember2402" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div class="avatar-info-cell">
            <div class="avatar-image">
              <figure data-test-user-avatar="" id="ember2404" class="profilepic  avatar-icon avatar-icon--small avatar-icon--circle ember-view"> <span data-test-avatar-text="profile_font_text" id="ember2405" class="avatar-block avatar__initial avatar__initial--2 ember-view"><span class="avatar__initial--icon-wrapper">
                    L
                  </span>
                </span>

                <!---->
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div data-test-id="table-view-contact" id="ember2406" class="avatar-text text__content requester-hover ember-view">
              <div id="ember2407" class="ember-view"> <a href="/a/contacts/77039361772" data-test-id="user-name" class="user">
                  Luciano D
                </a>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 30px" id="ember2409" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-autorefresh ember-view">
        <!---->
      </td>
      <td style="width: 24vw" id="ember2411" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="subject_test_label" id="ember2412" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div id="ember2413" class="pr-12 ticket-listview-hover __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__ticket-subject-popover ember-view">
            <div id="ember2414" class="ember-view">
              <div data-test-id="ticket-subject-hover-2454" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3804" tabindex="-1" data-ebd-id="ember3804-trigger" role="button" id="ember3805" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <a data-test-link="tickets-subject-2454" href="/a/tickets/2454" id="ember3806" class="link-on-hover link-no-underline wordbreak-fix ember-view">D / Enel - other (CS) #210100 test
                  <span data-test-ticket-id="2454" class="muted">
                    #2454
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3804" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>



            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 400px" id="ember2416" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="_test_label" id="ember2417" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="assign-to-hover" id="ember2418" class="group-agent ember-view">
            <div data-test-id="group-agent" id="ember3879" class="__module-tickets__assign-to ember-view">
              <div class="group-field  pr-5 mb-0">
                <div data-test-id="group-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Gruppo">

                  <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3881" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3881-trigger" role="button" id="ember3882" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> En Sp

                    </span>
                    <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3881" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="agent-field border-left--none">
                  <div class="agent-filter pl-0 mt-0">
                    <div data-test-id="agent-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Agente">

                      <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3887" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3887-trigger" role="button" id="ember3888" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> Luke D

                        </span>
                        <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3887" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2420" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="priority_test_label" id="ember2421" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="priority-hover" id="ember2422" class="priority ember-view">
            <div class="list-filter__label">
              <span class="tickets__list--low tickets__list--dropdown"></span> Low
              <!---->
            </div>

            <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon priority-icon"></span>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2424" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="statusTranslatedLabel_test_label" id="ember2425" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="status-hover" id="ember2426" class="status-select ember-view">
            <div class="pull-left list-filter__label" aria-label="Stato">
              Open
              <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2427" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="company.name_test_label" id="ember2428" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 180px" id="ember2429" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="createdAt_test_label" id="ember2430" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> 21º set 2020, 09:19 AM
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2431" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2432" class="hcell-template ember-view"> Waiting customer reply
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 200px" id="ember2433" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="stats.requesterRespondedAt_test_label" id="ember2434" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> 14 hours ago
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2435" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2436" class="hcell-template ember-view"> Waiting customer reply
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2437" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_checkbox_test_label" id="ember2438" class="hcell-template ember-view"> No
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr data-test-id="ticket-row-2385" data-row-id="ember2439" colspan="1" id="ember2440" class="lt-row is-selectable ember-view">
      <td style="width: 50px" id="ember2441" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div id="ember2442" class="ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="table-checkbox" id="ember2443" class="input __ui-form__custom-checkbox custom-checkbox ember-view"><input data-test-checkbox="ticket-checkbox-ember2443" id="checkbox-ember2443" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-checkbox ember-view" type="checkbox">
            <label for="checkbox-ember2443">
              <span class="label-field"></span>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 12vw" id="ember2444" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="customer_test_label" id="ember2445" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div class="avatar-info-cell">
            <div class="avatar-image">
              <figure data-test-user-avatar="" id="ember2447" class="profilepic  avatar-icon avatar-icon--small avatar-icon--circle ember-view"> <span data-test-avatar-text="profile_font_text" id="ember2448" class="avatar-block avatar__initial avatar__initial--3 ember-view"><span class="avatar__initial--icon-wrapper">
                    A
                  </span>
                </span>

                <!---->
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div data-test-id="table-view-contact" id="ember2449" class="avatar-text text__content requester-hover ember-view">
              <div id="ember2450" class="ember-view"> <a href="/a/contacts/77039270383" data-test-id="user-name" class="user">
                  Alessio B
                </a>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 30px" id="ember2452" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-autorefresh ember-view">
        <!---->
      </td>
      <td style="width: 24vw" id="ember2454" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="subject_test_label" id="ember2455" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div id="ember2456" class="pr-12 ticket-listview-hover __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__ticket-subject-popover ember-view">
            <div id="ember2457" class="ember-view">
              <div data-test-id="ticket-subject-hover-2385" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3799" tabindex="-1" data-ebd-id="ember3799-trigger" role="button" id="ember3800" class="trigger-shortcuts ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <a data-test-link="tickets-subject-2385" href="/a/tickets/2385" id="ember3801" class="link-on-hover link-no-underline wordbreak-fix ember-view">B / cars - other (MI) #209884
                  <span data-test-ticket-id="2385" class="muted">
                    #2385
                  </span>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3799" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>



            </div>
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 400px" id="ember2459" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="_test_label" id="ember2460" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="assign-to-hover" id="ember2461" class="group-agent ember-view">
            <div data-test-id="group-agent" id="ember3831" class="__module-tickets__assign-to ember-view">
              <div class="group-field  pr-5 mb-0">
                <div data-test-id="group-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Gruppo">

                  <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3833" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3833-trigger" role="button" id="ember3834" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> Product

                    </span>
                    <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3833" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                </div>
                <div class="agent-field border-left--none">
                  <div class="agent-filter pl-0 mt-0">
                    <div data-test-id="agent-select" class="assign-to-select hcell-template hint hint--left pl-10 pr-10" aria-label="Agente">

                      <div aria-activedescendant="-1" aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3839" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember3839-trigger" role="button" id="ember3840" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view"> <span class="ember-power-select-selected-item"> Michael

                        </span>
                        <!----><span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
                      </div>
                      <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember3839" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content-placeholder" style="display: none;"></div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2463" class="lt-cell align-left lt-cell-truncate ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="priority_test_label" id="ember2464" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="priority-hover" id="ember2465" class="priority ember-view">
            <div class="list-filter__label">
              <span class="tickets__list--low tickets__list--dropdown"></span> Low
              <!---->
            </div>

            <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon priority-icon"></span>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2467" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="statusTranslatedLabel_test_label" id="ember2468" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view">
          <div data-test-id="status-hover" id="ember2469" class="status-select ember-view">
            <div class="pull-left list-filter__label" aria-label="Stato">
              Open
              <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
            </div>

          </div>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 120px" id="ember2470" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="company.name_test_label" id="ember2471" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 180px" id="ember2472" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="createdAt_test_label" id="ember2473" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> 18º set 2020, 06:13 AM
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2474" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2475" class="hcell-template ember-view"> <span class="inactive">- -</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 200px" id="ember2476" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="stats.requesterRespondedAt_test_label" id="ember2477" class="hcell-template __module-tickets__tickets-list__tickets-table__cell-renderer ember-view"> 14 hours ago
          <!---->
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2478" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_dropdown_test_label" id="ember2479" class="hcell-template ember-view"> Waiting customer reply
        </div>
      </td>
      <td style="width: 160px" id="ember2480" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
        <div data-test-id="custom_checkbox_test_label" id="ember2481" class="hcell-template ember-view"> No
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>



<span class="muted">
  Muted class else where
</span>
<br>
<br>
<span class="muted">
  Another muted span 
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
span["data-test-ticket-id"] {display:none}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use css by like this

```
span.muted {
   display: none;
}
```

or if you want to use jquery

```
$('span.muted').hide();
```

or

```
$('span.muted').css('display', 'none');
```

there are a lot way to hide something in html with css and jquery, you can use whatever you want

Answer (score 1):

As the comment said in your original question, just use CSS can do it:

```
.muted{
  display:none;
}
```

You can test it at **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dv9eythj/1/)**